# GridViewRow Headers placed above each other

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datarow

I am working on ASP.NET C#. I am populating gridview with data from database. There are columns to the GridView that is been bound with DataTable. I ant to group these columns with Header Rows. I tried to add these Header Rows to a GridView as the following (Sample code):

I tried manipulating with row index but nothing happened.

```
protected void AddHeaders()
{
    GridViewRow vesselInfoRow = new GridViewRow(1, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert);
    TableCell vesselInfotc = new TableCell();
    vesselInfotc.Text = "Vessel Information ";
    vesselInfotc.Style.Add("text-align", "center");
    vesselInfotc.Style.Add("font-size", "medium");
    vesselInfotc.Style.Add("font-weight", "bold");
    vesselInfotc.Style.Add("background-color", "#b7dee8");
    vesselInfotc.Style.Add("color", "black");
    vesselInfotc.ColumnSpan = 4;
    vesselInfoRow.Cells.Add(vesselInfotc);
    this.BerthScoreCardGridView.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, vesselInfoRow);

    //
    GridViewRow vesselArrivalRow = new GridViewRow(1, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert);

    TableCell vesselArrivaltc = new TableCell();
    vesselArrivaltc.Text = "Vessel Arrival ";
    vesselArrivaltc.Style.Add("text-align", "center");
    vesselArrivaltc.Style.Add("font-size", "medium");
    vesselArrivaltc.Style.Add("font-weight", "bold");
    vesselArrivaltc.Style.Add("background-color", "#b7dee8");
    vesselArrivaltc.Style.Add("color", "black");
    vesselArrivaltc.ColumnSpan = 2;
    vesselArrivalRow.Cells.Add(vesselArrivaltc);

    this.BerthScoreCardGridView.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, vesselArrivalRow);


}
```

However the rows are placed above each other as the following:

[image: Screenshot of Page]

How can i place them horizontally next to each other. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add all the cells to the same row and add that single row to the GridView:

```
protected void AddHeaders()
{
    GridViewRow topHeaderRow = new GridViewRow(1, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert);

    TableCell vesselInfotc = new TableCell();
    vesselInfotc.Text = "Vessel Information ";
    ...
    vesselInfotc.ColumnSpan = 4;
    topHeaderRow.Cells.Add(vesselInfotc);

    TableCell vesselArrivaltc = new TableCell();
    vesselArrivaltc.Text = "Vessel Arrival ";
    ...
    vesselArrivaltc.ColumnSpan = 2;
    topHeaderRow.Cells.Add(vesselArrivaltc);

    // Add the other cells here
    ...

    BerthScoreCardGridView.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, topHeaderRow);
}
```

And call your function in the `PreRender` event of the GridView:

```
void BerthScoreCardGridView_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddHeaders();
}
```